# How can a process in "interruptible sleep" state use 100% CPU?

Tags: linux, process

According to this [reference](https://idea.popcount.org/2012-12-11-linux-process-states/), a process has the following states

```
R  running or runnable (on run queue)
D  uninterruptible sleep (usually IO)
S  interruptible sleep (waiting for an event to complete)
Z  defunct/zombie, terminated but not reaped by its parent
T  stopped, either by a job control signal or because it is being traced
```

In the sleep state, it is not expected that process consumes CPU time, however in the output below, I see that a process is using 100% of cpu and at the same time, it is in S state.

```
  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND
32643 root      20   0 13736 7748  472 R   98  0.0   2:59.30 bzip2
29504 satam     20   0 1063m 779m 3824 S  100  2.4   1242:54 stencil
31923 root      20   0 15092 1224  848 D   14  0.0   1:39.96 find
```

How that is possible and what does that mean?

Answer (score 1):

"uninterruptible sleep" means that the process is waiting on I/O (disk operations for example).  But given that the CPU is running the process, even though it isn't doing work, the CPU is still "stuck" waiting for it to complete the io, so it can get on with something else - to schedule another task.  So this consumes 100% of cycles of the CPU when the process is in D mode.

So it is in sleep mode, in than that it isn't doing any CPU work, but is uninterruptible which means the CPU can't do anything else.

In a multi-core system, the other cores are available for other tasks.

Comment: Missed it by **that** much! {/Max Smart Voice} The 'S' (stencil) process, not the 'D' (find).  But you're right.

Comment: It goes without question that interruptible tasks should not consume CPU time. I don't know how OP got that screenshot, though. This answer seems to suggest that uninterruptible tasks can consume CPU in the sense that the CPU is stuck with the task because the task is not affected by signal. I think this could use more explanation. From what I know, I don't think uninterruptible tasks should consume CPU time at all, just like interruptible tasks.

Comment: I don't think the CPU is "stuck" with the task at all. Because the scheduler chooses what to run next from "runnable" tasks. According to Linux Kernel Development by Robert Love (which based on Kernel 4.x I think), uninterruptible sleep and interruptible sleep tasks both are not runnable - scheduler won't consider them for next task to be run. This has nothing to do with the fact that they are uninterruptible, which means you can't kill it with signal like SIGTERM. The point is these tasks are not even considered to be scheduled so they should not consume CPU time.

Comment: I think the "CPU is stuck" with something when the scheduler can't preempt it - ex: an interrupt handler could be such a thing. I'm not sure an interrupt handler is considered a "task" (and as such has the notion of uninterruptible) on Linux, though.

Answer (score 0):

Lets look at the picture:

```
 PID  USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND
29504 satam     20   0 1063m 779m 3824 S  100  2.4   1242:54 stencil
```

The process is in 'S' state but cpu usage = 100%.

It doesnt make sense however we will find it right now.

"Top" shows the state of the process at moment right now. It is a characteristic
of the particular point of time. So the process is sleeping "RIGHT NOW".

But the cpu usage is not the characterisitic about instance of time it is a characteristic about the interval of time. It is the average cpu usage during the interval of time between now and some time before: from (t-delta) to t.
Where t is the moment of time right now.

So. right now the process is sleeping and it uses cpu for 0%.
But (for example) 1 second ago the process used 100% of cpu. So top make
caclulation: (100%+0%)/1s = 100%.

Does it make sense?

So 'S' is the state of the process right now. But cpu usage column
is the avarage cpu usage between now and some time before.
Thats why it makes sense.

Let me give some other example:

```
  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND                                                                                                                   
11568 vasya     20   0 28,558g 175004  92304 S   5,6  1,1  10:33.09 chrome
```

Chrome is in 'S' state however top shows that it is using 5,6% CPU.
It doesnt make any sense. How is the process in 'S' state can consume cpu. Right? Actually it makes sense.

The process is in 'S' state right now. However some time before it was in 'R' state.

Look, let's check the state of chrome very quickly:

```
$ while true; do cat /proc/11568/stat | awk '{print $3}'; done
S
S
R
S
S
S
S
S
S
S
S
R
S
S
```

Most of the time chrome in is "S" state so "top" with great possibility will read the "S" state from procfs and show to us. However it doesnt mean that chrome is in 'S' state all the time as you can see.

So if at point of time = 0s we have cpu usage 5.6%  (state 'R')
and at the next moment of time =1s we have 0% cpu usage (state 'S") then
top make calculation to find out the average =>  (5.6%+0)/(1-0) = 5.6%

The process is sleeping RIGHT NOW. ('S' column).
However cpu usage is not about right now characteritic. It is the average value of cpu usage by the process FOR THE LAST THREE SECONDS.(top by default
is redreshing every three seconds).

Hope it makes clarification about the topic.